# silverlight media play stop state

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-toolkit

I am using SMF silverlight media player. I am using the following code to get me the current volume on player

```
this.item = function(){
        alert(this.player.GetVolume());
    }
```

which works fine but I also want the current status of the media. Whats the property for that. I didn't see that in API docs

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want the `PlayState` property, which is of type `MediaPluginState` and can be one of these values:

- Closed
- Opening
- Buffering
- Playing
- Paused
- Stopped
- Individualizing
- AcquiringLicense
- ClipPlaying

Comment: @Autolycus - I'm not sure of the JavaScript code to access it, but in C# it would be 'this.player.PlayState == MediaPluginState.Closed`. I don't see a `GetVolume` method in the latest version of SMF, which can be found [here](http://smf.codeplex.com/).

Comment: there is a VolumeLevel property - btw, from my OnApplyTemplate override at a SMFPlayer descendent I call     protected void UpdateVolumeElement()
    {
           if (VolumeElement != null)
        VolumeElement.VolumeLevel = VolumeLevel;
    } since it seems the UI element doesn't update the volume UI at startup with the VolumeElement value set to the player at XAML